# How to save data on session in the main Controller in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to get the location of user from IP address and save it on session, and I'm using the main Controller, but this query run in every request, so the `if (! session()->has('priceGroup'))` is not working. Some advice to improve this code?

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (! session()->has('priceGroup')) {
            session(['priceGroup' => Country::with(['priceGroup'])->select('id')->where('code', getCountryCodeFromIp())->first()->priceGroup->first()]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your controller is constructed the middleware that deals with the session has not yet run. So `if(session())` will return `false` always. This will be same for the AppServiceProvider too. I suggest you to create a middleware

Comment: This logic should be moved to a new middleware that is placed after the session middleware

Comment: Thank you. I already moved it to a middleware and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your code in the controller method (not in a __construct).